# Found corrupted data while opening file using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I've been able to query from a Google Sheets table just fine for the past 6 months to a year and then all of a sudden I'm receiving the error: "Found corrupted data while opening file." Does anyone know why this is occurring even though there were no changes made to the Google Sheet.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My tables' source format was CSV while using a spreadsheets.
To solve it, I deleted the table and recreated it with "Google Sheet" as source format.
For other tables I couldn't delete, I changed the source format by making a REST call.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/update

Both solutions worked.

Answer (score 1):

this happens occasionally...the error is on Google's side. the best course of action is to contact Google Sheets support and request recovery of your spreadsheet. it may take them 1-3 weeks to do so.

[image: 0]